# MVC Kendo UI - Pass view data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I am new to MVC Kendo. I am creating a sample programme with one Datetimepicker, two combo boxes and grid. What I want to know when I select the dropdownboxes data and datetime picker date I want to populate Grid. I have done some work, but I can't find the way to send  selected dropdown and datetimepicker values to controller when I click the Search button. If any one knows please let me know.

Razor View-

```
@using PortalModels

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Date")</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>@Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("DTPicker")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("District")</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("Districts")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .Placeholder("Select category...")
              .DataTextField("CdNm")
              .DataValueField("CdKy")
              .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeDistrict", "MarketInfo");
                  });
              })
        )
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Market")</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("Markets")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .Placeholder("Select product...")
              .DataTextField("CdNm")
              .DataValueField("CdKy")
              .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
              .DataSource(source => {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeMarket", "MarketInfo")
                          .Data("filterMarkets");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .CascadeFrom("Districts")
        )
        <script>
            function filterMarkets() {
                return {
                    categories: $("#Districts").val(),
                    productFilter: $("#Markets").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
                };
            }
        </script>
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="Submittbn" /></td>
    </tr>
</table> 

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PortalModels.MarketInfoModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(m => m.ItmNm).Width(400);
          columns.Bound(m => m.Unit).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(m => m.Unit).Width(150);
      })
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
          dataSource.Ajax()
          .ServerOperation(false)
          .Read(read => read.Action("ReadMarketInfoDetails", "MarketInfo").Data("MarketData"))
          .Create(create => create.Action("FamilyDetails", "Home").Data("FamilyData"))
          .PageSize(150)// Action method invoked when the grid needs data

      )
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable() // Enable sorting
)


<script>
    $(function () {
        var MarketGrid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
        $("#Submittbn").click(function () {
            MarketGrid.dataSource.read();
        })
    });

    function MarketData() {
        var EffectiveDtValue = $("#DTPicker").data("kendoDatePicker")
        var DistrictValue = $('#Districts').data("kendoComboBox")
        var MarketValue = $('#Markets').data("kendoComboBox")
        return {
            intEmpky: EffectiveDt.value(),
            intAdrKy: DistrictValue.value(),
            strCode: MarketValue.value()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I used kendo server controls, and was having some difficulties like this only. Then I tried using Kendo controls using jQuery. Its easy to implement.

Comment: hey has there been any progress to this?

Answer (score 2):

**View**

- Important to use `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and to enclose your Kendo Controls ( any model properties ) within the form tag
- `@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Prospects)` // you want to use DropDownListFor to bind to model
- You want to keep the `.Name("Prospects")` property assigned to your DropDownListFor ( Not ur issue but still important)

**View Model**

```
    public class ViewModelCCTRST
    {
        .
        ..
        public string Prospects { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<dbProspect> AvailableProspects { get; set; }
        .
        ..
        ...
     }
```

**Post Method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModelCCTRST model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string pro = model.Prospects;
            string cnt = model.Countys;
            string twn = model.TownShips;
            string rng = model.Ranges;
            string sct = model.Sections;
            string trt = model.Tracts;
```

If you follow these steps you should find your values bound to your model!

Hope this helps

Comment: Don Thomas Boyle, thanks for answering this question. You happen to be the only one on the whole internet addressing this issue. Stumbled upon this after hours of research. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**VIEW**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Label("Date")
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>@Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("DTPicker")
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Label("District")
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("Districts")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
          .Placeholder("Select category...")
                   .DataTextField("Text")
                          .DataValueField("Value")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCascadeDistrict", "Home");
              });
          })
    )
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Label("Market")
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("Markets")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
          .Placeholder("Select product...")
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCascadeMarket", "Home")
                      .Data("filterMarkets");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
          .Enable(false)
          .AutoBind(false)
          .CascadeFrom("Districts")
    )
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="Submittbn" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.TestModels>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(m => m.ID).Width(100);
      columns.Bound(m => m.Name).Width(700);
  })
  .DataSource(dataSource =>
      dataSource.Ajax()
      .ServerOperation(false)
                      .Read(read => read.Action("GridRead", "Home").Data("MarketData"))
      .PageSize(150)

  )
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable())
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult GridRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string intEmpky, string intAdrKy, string strCode)
    {
        List<TestModels> models = new List<TestModels>();


        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {

            TestModels model = new TestModels();
            model.ID = i;
            model.Name = intEmpky + "_" + intAdrKy + "_" + strCode;
            models.Add(model);

        }

        return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetCascadeDistrict()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> models = new List<SelectListItem>();


        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {

            SelectListItem model = new SelectListItem();
            model.Value = i.ToString();
            model.Text = "text" + i;
            models.Add(model);

        }

        return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetCascadeMarket(string categories, string productFilter)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> models = new List<SelectListItem>();


        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {

            SelectListItem model = new SelectListItem();
            model.Value = i.ToString();
            model.Text = "text" + i;
            models.Add(model);

        }

        return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Note : Please update "MarketData()" function in your JS code.

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Where is the `HTTPPOST`?? how to read value from his Combobox?

Comment: The Filter works fine, the values get to the dropboxes, all 5 cascading ones. I cannot get the values back out of the dropboxes into my Controller ( say i want to save all the dropdownlist values in a textfile ) i need them, and cannot get to them.